# Is it possible to have the same codebase for Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

I need install 2 instances of Tomcat. 
Is it possible to use the same codebase but run on different ports?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain further? What is motivating you to run two instances of Tomcat on the same machine? I think what you are asking is possible, but I am not sure if it is what you actually want. I can read your question as (1) Run the same app on different ports (e.g., 80 and 443) or (2) Run two separate instances of the same app on two separate installations of Tomcat. #1 makes sense. #2 is possible but I am not sure what would motivate this.

Comment: Motivation simple - I don't have 2 machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [tomcat virtual hosts](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) ([by port number](http://ex-parrot.com/~pete/tomcat-vhost.html)) to direct flows to correct directories

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. But you will need to duplicate some of the install directories. Please see: http://kief.com/node/23

Comment: You will be using the same "codebase" - that is...the bin dir of tomcat and all libs. You will just need to specify different configuration for each instance (at least for the port) and a different set of apps. If this doesn't suit your purposes, you will need to elaborate on your question.